# How do I handle events using a Tkinter GUI and my main loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, event-handling

Does the majority of my event handling happen for a Tkinter GUI happen outside of my main loop? When I create a GameWindow instance and run the code below in my main loop it generates the GUI with all the buttons. The problem I'm having is that I'm having to implement the logic within the methods of my `GameWindow` and Letter class. For instance, once a player selects a difficulty setting the `select_difficulty_setting` method starts a chain of events that essentially runs my game (albeit not successfully).

This seems incredibly wrong from a programming standpoint. I would think that methods should only be concerned with their particular job and should not be involved in the logic of how my game is supposed to run.

The problem is when I try to implement the game logic in my main loop the GUI never comes up. The main loop and the GUI seem to be doing separate things and there's no way for me to initialize the GUI in my main loop and have it wait for player-driven events. How do I handle the logic of the game and the event handling of Tkinter?

By the way, my `root = Tk()` main loop only calls the `GameWindow` class. I haven't been able to implement any logic in my main loop because the events/variables that I created in my classes seem to be disregarded.

```
import tkinter as tk
from Functions import Word_Generator as wg

GAME_WIDTH = 700
GAME_HEIGHT = 600
LETTER_WIDTH = 25
LETTER_HEIGHT = 25

alphabet = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M',
        'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

class GameWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title('Hangman')

        self.hiddenword = 'Nothing'
        self.alphabet = alphabet
        self.letterguessed = ''
        self.difficultysetting = 'Nothing'
        self.alphxpos = 330
        self.alphypos = 450

        container = tk.Frame(master, height=GAME_HEIGHT, width=GAME_WIDTH)
        container.pack()

        # Initial Hangman Background and Title
        background_image = tk.PhotoImage(file=r"D:\Python\Projects\Hangman\Images\Platform_3.png").subsample(6, 6)
        background_label = tk.Label(image=background_image)
        background_label.image = background_image
        background_label.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1, x=-200, y=50)


        self.button1 = tk.Button(master, height=1, width=4, text="Easy",  font=('Courier', 12), command=lambda: self.select_difficulty_setting('E'))
        self.button2 = tk.Button(master, height=1, width=12, 
text="Intermediate", font=('Courier', 12), command=lambda: self.select_difficulty_setting('I'))
        self.button3 = tk.Button(master, height=1, width=4, text="Hard", font=('Courier', 12), command=lambda: self.select_difficulty_setting('H'))
        self.button4 = tk.Button(master, height=1, width=4, text="QUIT", font=('Courier', 12), command=lambda: print("QUIT"))
        self.button5 = tk.Button(master, height=1, width=4, text="MENU", font=('Courier', 12), command=lambda: self.reset_game(master))
        self.button1.place(x=475, y=200)
        self.button2.place(x=435, y=235)
        self.button3.place(x=475, y=270)
        self.button4.place(x=650, y=0)
        self.button5.place(x=600, y=0)

    def select_difficulty_setting(self, setting):
        self.difficultysetting = setting
        self.clear_difficulty_settings_widget()

    def clear_difficulty_settings_widget( self ):
        self.button1.place_forget()
        self.button2.place_forget()
        self.button3.place_forget()
        self.generate_hidden_word(self.difficultysetting)

    def generate_alphabet(self):
        firstrowxpos = self.alphxpos
        secondrowxpos = self.alphxpos
        for letters in alphabet[:13]:
            LetterButton(letters, firstrowxpos, self.alphypos)
            firstrowxpos += LETTER_WIDTH

        for letters in alphabet[13:26]:
            LetterButton(letters, secondrowxpos, self.alphypos + LETTER_HEIGHT)
            secondrowxpos += LETTER_WIDTH
        self.generate_hidden_word_spaces()

    def generate_hidden_word(self, difficultysetting):
        self.difficultysetting = difficultysetting
        self.hiddenword = list(wg.get_random_word(difficultysetting).upper())
        self.generate_alphabet()
        return self.hiddenword

    def generate_hidden_word_spaces(self):
        blankspaces = list('_' * len(self.hiddenword))
        label = tk.Label(self.master, text=blankspaces, font=('Courier', 30))
        label.place(x=325, y=235)
        print(self.hiddenword)

    def update_hidden_word_spaces(self):
        print('Hi')

    def player_guesses(self):
        self.letterguessed = str(input('Guess a letter\n').upper())
        print(self.letterguessed)
        return self.letterguessed

    def check_players_guess(self):
        if self.letterguessed in self.hiddenword:
            print('You Guessed Correctly!')
            return True
        else:
            print('Sorry, ' + self.letterguessed + 'is not in the word.  
            Guess again.')
            return False


class LetterButton:
    def __init__(self, letter, xpos, ypos):
        self.letter = letter
        self.button = tk.Button(text=letter, font=('Courier', 21), bd=0, 
        command=self.select_letter)
        self.button.place(x=xpos, y=ypos, width=25, height=25)

    def select_letter(self):
        GameWindow.letterguessed = self.letter
        GameWindow.check_players_guess()
        self.destroy_letter()

    def destroy_letter(self):
        self.button.destroy()

    def return_letter(self):
        return self.letter
```

Comment: The sentence _"Does the majority of my event handling happen for a Tkinter GUI happen outside of my main loop? "_ makes no sense. Absolutely no event handling happens outside of the main loop.  Given that your code never calls `mainloop` or `update`, I don't see how it could possibly handle any events at all.

Comment: At least part of the problem is that your `GameWindow` inherits from `tk.Tk`. I can't see any reason at all why you are doing that, since it appears you're already creating a root window somewhere else. When I make `GameWindow` inherit from nothing, and I create an explicit root, the code seems to work.